# Autoplay videos using Fancybox to open video served from Vimeo via Channel Videos

Tags: ee2, channel-videos, vimeo, modal

I am using [Channel Videos](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_videos/) from [DevDemon](http://www.devdemon.com/) to pop up videos in a [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) modal. The videos are hosted on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/). Does anyone know how to make the videos autoplay?

I am looping through the relational entries like so:

```
<ul class="portfolio recent-work clearfix">
    {exp:channel:entries 
        disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination" 
        category="1" 
        channel="program_module" 
        status="open" 
        show_future_entries="no" 
        show_expired="no" 
    }
        {video_groups_to_include}
            {exp:channel_videos:videos 
                status="open" 
                entry_id="{video_groups_to_include:entry_id}" 
            }
                <li data-id='id-{video:id}' class='{video_groups_to_include:categories}{category_url_title}{/video_groups_to_include:categories}'>
                    <a href="{site_url}_video/{video:id}" data-html="{site_url}_video/{video:id}" class="fancybox-lesson player" data-rel="fancybox-lesson" title="{video:title}">
                        <em class="overflow-hidden"><img src="{video:img_url_hd}" alt="{video:title}" /></em>
                        <span>
                            <strong>{video:title}</strong>
                            <i>{video:description}</i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
        {/video_groups_to_include}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Then the video embed is done here:

```
{if logged_out}
    {redirect="{site_url}"}
{/if}
{if logged_in}
    {exp:channel_videos:videos 
        status="open" 
        video_id="{segment_2}" 
        embed_width="630" 
        embed_height="354"
    }
        {video:embed_code_hd}
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
{/if}
```

The js to kick off the modal is here:

```
jQuery(".fancybox-lesson").fancybox({
    'padding'       : 0,
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'title'         : this.title,
    'width'         : 630,
    'height'        : 354,
    'href'          : this.href,
    'type'          : 'ajax'
});
```

I don't care at which stage I accomplish this as long as it occurs once the video is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding '?autoplay=1' to the end of your video link URL after the video id.

Comment: I don't have that option. I am using Channel Videos to manage videos and thus the {video:embed_code_hd} tag.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit the 'js to kick off the modal' then?  Does something like 'href'          : this.href + '?autoplay=1' work?